# c++ set with structs, set.find() function making error 'invalid comparator'

Tags: c++

I make set of structs.
My struct has one array with length 8 inside as pointer.
If I insert some structs to the set, it's okay.
But when I try to find, error('invalid comparator') occurs.
Here is my code.

```
struct Key {
    int* arr;
};

bool operator<(const Key& a, const Key& b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (a.arr[i] == b.arr[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return a.arr[i] < b.arr[i];
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool operator==(const Key& a, const Key& b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (a.arr[i] != b.arr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


    set<Key> visit;
    visit.insert(initKey);

......

                Key key;
                key.arr = newcandidate;

                visit.find(key); -> trigger error.
```

I want to add arrays to somewhere.
Then I want to find some arrays in there fastly.
So I try to use 'set' structures.
What do I need to do to solve this problem?
Thank you very much for your reading.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: Have a look also into `std::array<int, 8>`.

Comment: I have never seen operators implmented as free functions beeing used as default comparator for std containers. It might be fine, though to say what is the problem, you need to include a complete example

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/OSA4t9).

Comment: Your `operator<()` has a flaw: If it reaches the end of function this means that all `a.arr` and `b.arr` elements were equal pair-wise. Hence, `a.arr == b.arr;` Hence, the function should `return false;` in  this case. (If they are equal, `a < b` should result in `false`.) I once realized that VisualStudio has debug code in `std::set` which can uncover such wrong behavior at runtime (they simply test something like `assert((b < a) == !(a < b));` which would fail for your `operator<()`) - other std libraries might provide a similar option.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad question. I'm very new in this site, please let it slide and thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Now I change the last code to return false, and it works properly. I cannot reproduce the problem that I mentioned when the set's size is small, but when it's getting bigger, it occurs error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define properly only operator<. The operator== is not relevant to the set.
You should return false at last row. The relation is strict.
It shouldn't be possible to have a < b and b < a, but your operator is defined to be a < a.